# What does it mean for something other than food to be "deep fried"?

Tags: idiom-meaning

A meme was described to be "deep fried". I think it might have meant that its message was maybe an exaggeration of facts?

https://www.reddit.com/r/antinatalism/comments/cxs224/deep_fried_antinatalism_meme/

Comment: Hello, CL. Please add a linked reference so that it's clear it's a reasonably common usage. Have you looked up the expression yourself? The Urban Dictionary gives information, but the expression seems non-standard and abusive/taboo.

Comment: In what context? Please provide some examples. I would say it's simply a metaphor—although the one answer certainly provides a different approach.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've linked the Reddit post

Comment: Thanks, but I meant some other example (or preferably examples) _so that it's clear it's a reasonably common usage_. ELU deals with standard or at least widespread usages, not single usages.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an expression used to refer to pictures which have been modified by filters. The final effect is like the image had been “fried”.

From [knowyourmeme.com](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/deep-fried-memes?full=1):

> ***Deep Fried Memes*** are a style of meme wherein an image is run through dozens of filters to the point where the image appears grainy, washed-out, and strangely colored. Often, they’re applied in memes popular on Black Twitter such as Real Nigga Hours and Spell ICUP Nigga.

Example:

[image]

Comment: C'est le chapeau qui fait le sorcier.